# Plasma concentrations Of Beta-Carotene and Retinol

Tags: micronutrients, blood-tests, concentration

I'm doing an analysis, and retinol and beta carotene are involved. 
I need to know :

1) Normal levels of dietary beta carotene and Retinol consumed (mcg per day);

2) Normal levels of plasma retinol and Beta carotene (ng/ml);

3) Is it possible a plasma beta carotene equals zero?

I'm talking about intervals. Which values are considered to be too high or too small?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Can you please clarify what sort of an analysis are you going to do. Give your blood for analysis? Work in a lab to determine the concentrations of beta carotene and retinol in different samples? Something else? You can always [edit] your question to include additional information. Thanks!